# Static method ‘buildBlock’ requires that ‘Text’ conform to ‘View’

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I am trying to add SwiftUI in existing UIKit Project. I could not understand why I am getting this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTxnP.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for these type of issues is accessing this way "SwiftUI.UIelement". This issue happens when we have existing class or struct with same name as the UI element we are using from SwiftUI. So by putting SWiftUI.UIElement we specify which UI element we are referring to.